# PHP Show Login if Logged out

Tags: php, session, authentication

Hey, this is a simple question.

How can I show a login button if a user is logged out and show a logout button if a user is logged in?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Assuming `$_SESSION['logged-in']` is the session variable that represents the state of being logged in:

```
if ($_SESSION['logged-in']) {
    echo '<button>log off</button>';
} else {
    echo '<button>log in</button>';
}
```

Comment: @Nullbyte: Is this really what you wanted to know?

Comment: Yeah, I'm a bit of a noob and I just wanted to make some buttons like that.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php
Remember to init the session before accessing session variables, otherwise you may spend many hours debugging ;)